Azure Table Storage Query with Timestamp Filter Returns Inconsistent Page Sizes
We have an Azure Table Storage setup where we store a large amount of data for different organizations. We use the Organization ID as the partition key.
For some operations, we need to fetch data from the last 24 hours for a particular organization. We've written the following code to achieve this, using pagination to handle large datasets. According to our logic, each page should return 1,000 entities.
The code works perfectly when filtering only by the partition key; each page returns 1,000 entities as expected. However, when we add an additional filter for the Timestamp, the results become inconsistent. Some pages return 100 entities, others return 60, and some even return as few as 0 or 1 entities. This seems like a bug in the SDK.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a known workaround or a fix for this? Could this be an issue with how the SDK handles compound filters, or is there something wrong with the logic in the code?
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> RetrieveEntitiesWithDailyFilterAsync(string tableName, string partitionKey)
{
    List<T> entities = new List<T>();
    //List<TableEntity> entities = new List<TableEntity>();
    string continuationToken = null;

    // Calculate the date and time 24 hours ago from now
    DateTime fromDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-24);

    // Build the predicate to filter by PartitionKey and Timestamp
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.Build<T>(x => x.PartitionKey == partitionKey);
    //for daily
    // predicate = predicate.AndAlso(x => x.Timestamp >= fromDate);
   
    do
    {
        
        var _tableClient = _tableServiceClient.GetTableClient(tableName);

        // Query the table with the predicate and maxPerPage
        var queryResult = _tableClient.QueryAsync<T>(predicate, maxPerPage: 1000);

        // Iterate through pages of results
        await foreach (var page in queryResult.AsPages(continuationToken))
        {
            continuationToken = page.ContinuationToken;
            entities.AddRange(page.Values);
        }
    } while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken));

    return entities;
}

Thanks
Utpal

This is expected behavior. What you are seeing is the documented behavior mentioned here.

You just need to ensure that you are handling continuation token in your code to get the desired entities.

But when I add timestamp filter it is not returning 1000 entities at any iteration

It is not guaranteed that you will always get exactly 1000 entities. At times you may also get 0 entities back even though there are entities matching your query. What is guaranteed is that you will never get more than 1000 entities in a single request.

Per day we store nearly 4-5k data per partition key and we want to retrive all of them.If this kind of inconsistent behaviour we face then for fetchich all data will take huge amount of time .is there any alternate way to retrive data in a faster way.

If you need to fetch all data for a day without including the partition key in your query, I would recommend rethinking about how you want to store the data. May be create another copy of your data where the partition key is the date.
